# Abrir Modal usando ajax, Datatables y Bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap, datatables

estoy creando una tabla con Datatables y Boostrap, para mostrar registros traidos desde una base de datos Mysql.
Muestro imagen de mi proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La situacion es que requiero mostrar informacion adicional de cada registro, a traves de un modal que se muestre al dar click al boton "INFO". Desafortunadamente, no esta mostrando dicho modal.
Aqui mi codigo:

```
<?php require('configuracion.php');?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <!-- JS -->
        <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
        <script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
        
        <!-- CCS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css">
<script>
    // script para llamar y configurar el datatable
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#datos').DataTable(
                    {
                        responsive: true,
                        autoWidth: false,
                            "language": {
                            "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por pagina",
                            "search": "Buscar:",
                            "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron coincidencias",
                            "info": "Mostrando la pagina _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
                            "infoEmpty": "No hay registros disponibles",
                            "infoFiltered": "(Filtro de _MAX_ total registros)",
                                "paginate": {
                                    "first": "Primero",
                                    "last": "Ultimo",
                                    "next": "Siguiente",
                                    "previous": "Anterior"
                                },
                        }
                    }
                );
        });
    </script>
<script>
            // script para mostrar la ventana modal
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(document).on('click', '.ver_dato', function(){
                    var personal_id = $(this).attr("id");
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"VistaPrevia.php",
                        method:"POST",
                        data:{personal_id:personal_id},
                        success:function(data){
                            $('#personal_detalles').html(data);
                            $('#ventana_modal').modal('show');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });  
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Conexion y consulta a B.D. -->
<?php
        $result = $connexion->query(
        'SELECT id, PARROQUIA, SECTOR, DIRECCION, SERVICIO, ESTATUS,FECHA FROM consulta_reporte'
        );
    ?>
    
    <?php if ($result->num_rows > 0) { ?>
<!-- DataTable -->  
<table id="datos" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" style="width:100%">
    
    <!-- Encabezado de datos----->
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Parroquia</th>
            <th>Sector</th>
            <th>Direccion</th>
            <th>Servicio</th>
            <th>Estatus</th>
            <th>Fecha</th>
            <th>Informacion</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = $row["id"];
        ?>
<!------------ Datos ---------------------------->
    
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['PARROQUIA']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['SECTOR']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['DIRECCION']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['SERVICIO']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['ESTATUS']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['FECHA']; ?></td>
            <td><input type="button" name="vista" 
            value="INFO" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" 
            class="btn btn-info btn-xs ver_dato" />
            </td>   
        </tr>
    
    <?php } ?>
    
</table>
<?php } ?>
<!------------------- VENTANA MODAL ------------------------------------------->
    <div id="ventana_modal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Detalles</h4>
                </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" id="personal_detalles">

                    </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--------------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

La consulta y el paso de parametros (id), las realiza sin problemas, de hecho en la consola del desarrollador (google chrome), muestra el resultado del modal, pero sin mostrar en pantalla dicho modal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He revisado muchas veces el codigo y foros, pero no consigo donde puede estar el problema. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida. Gracias

Comment: ¿el error que sale en consola se mostró después de que clickearas el botón de "Info"? Si es así, ¿qué te dice? Aparte creo que sería mejor que usaras json para mandar tus datos de tu php hacia tus vistas.

Comment: Hola, por consola no muestra error sobre la ventana del modal, de hecho muestra el preview tal como se muestra en la imagen.

Comment: Algo me dice que son las librerías del datatables, las referentes al JS de Bootstrap, trata de ir comentando una a una para que no corran, deja únicamente la de bootstrap.js y jquery.js y vas agregando funcionalidades hasta que mires el fallo

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo para que usas DataTables si estas pintando los registros con PHP, si lo pintas con DataTables los registro lo que pasa es lo siguiente. Cuando DataTables inserta un elemento al DOM y trata de añadirle un listener, a esas alturas ya se renderizó el DOM e interpretó los listeners. No va a escuchar directivas añadidas a mano por DataTables.